# S3 Cross account Access | Accessing Buckets via console of another Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created the Roles and policies according to the AWS document for the S3 cross account access and I'm able to list all the buckets and do stuff only using command Line.
I need all the buckets in Account 'A' to Account 'B' and buckets from Account 'A' should be visible in the Account 'B' S3 Console.
Is there a way for the Account 'A' buckets to appear in Account 'B' console?

Answer (score 1):

You can [switching to a role in AWS console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html). However, the use of console requires more permissions then just barely listing S3 buckets, thus you may find that you may need to add more permissions to your cross-account role.